# Dynamic syntax highlighting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting, contenteditable

I'm creating javascript editor with syntax highlighter based on `contentEditable` html element. I wrote a class that manages the editor and works like this:

```
function Editor() {
    this.setContent = function(content) {
         var pos = //Computes cursor position in current dom scope (number of characters from begining)
         editor.innerHTML = content;
         /* Here I set the cursor back, again, it is complicated and slow process*/
    }
    this.highlight = function() {
         this.setContent(someHighlighter.highlight(this.getTextContent()));  //Slow - highlights whole innerText of editor DOM and sets it as innerHTML
    }
}
```

The code above is just concept. But even so, you can see that it is not effective and you may understand I'm looking for beter alternative.
On the other side I dont want to spend the rest of my life doing this editor.

1. Is there some javascript syntax highlighter that works with DOM instead of pure text?
2. Is there some better way how to change element content without loosing cursor position?

Comment: Have you looked at how [other editors](http://codemirror.net/) do it?

Comment: I'm looking for the code concept, not the actual code to copy. If  did, I'd just use other editor and wouldn't make my own.

Comment: As it turns out, code is a *very* good place to find code concepts.

Comment: Well, in the end I decided to use the CodeMirror. When you posted it, I expected it to be another "Put this on your page and shut up" editor, but it showed to have awesome Api. But after looking in the code, I still don't understand how it actually works...